# Inconsistent Execution Sequence with await Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, async-await

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior in the execution sequence of my code. Here's the code snippet:

```
console.log("1");
await reloadScenarios();
console.log("2");

const reloadScenarios = () => {
    if (token) {
        getScenario()
            .then(({ scenarios }) => {
                console.log("3");

                const transformedScenarios = scenarios.map(option => ({
                    scenario: option.name,
                    description: option.categories.name,
                    value: option._id
                }));

                setOptions(transformedScenarios);
                // setSelectedOption(transformedScenarios[0]?.value || null);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Failed to fetch scenario options:', error);
            });
    }
};
```

I expected the execution sequence to be 1, 3, 2. However, when I run the code, the actual sequence is 1, 2, 3. Could someone please explain why this happens?

Additionally, I noticed that when I modify the reloadScenarios function to include a return statement before getScenario(), the execution sequence changes to 1, 3, 2 - which is the desired sequence. Do I really need the return statement, or is there another explanation to achieve the desired sequence?

Comment: You await reloadScenarios, but hang a “then” on the async function “getScenario”. There’s nothing to await as written.

Comment: @DaveNewton await statement won't wait for the `then` to finish? or it will at least wait for `getScenario` to finish? Or it will wait for none?

Comment: "*Do I really need the return statement?*" - yes, of course, if the `reloadScenarios()` call does not return anything then `await` cannot wait for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are using await to call a function which is not asynchronous and which does not return a Promise. Since the function does not return a Promise, then execution continues.

If you want the displayed sequence to be "1,3 2" then you have to mark your function with `async`

```js
const reloadScenarios = async () => {
    // Your body function
};
```

This way, when you mark `await reloadScenarios`, you are waiting for the promise to be resolved (or rejected).

For more details, see the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

**EDIT**
Sorry, I forgot, there is another problem: you also have to return the promise in your function

Comment: Just marking `reloadScenarios` as `async` does not suffice